# How can I tell whether a DC device will accept a greater voltage than stated?

Tags: voltage, dc, over-voltage-protection

Over the time, as an amateur, I've developed a sense that DC powered devices with internal circuitry should be fed with the voltage stated on the case. Having seen certain devices (e.g a portable USB hard disk with a separate power supply) suffer damage when fed with a +50% voltage (accidentally connected a 19v laptop brick to the 12v port, blowing out the TVS diodes on the HDD PCB) I thought correct voltage was relatively critical to DC components

I was somewhat surprised then, to acquire a 3com wireless access point that stated (10-30v) next to its DC connector. Latterly I successfully powered a cheapo ethernet switch, whose case said 9v, with a 12v adapter to seemingly no ill effects; it's been running well for months now

It thus seems to me that some DC devices are more sensitive than others to the feed voltage and I'd like to know if it's possible to work out whether they are or not

I'm asking specifically in this case because I'd like to know if the manufacturer provided mobility scooter motor controller I have here can be fed with 36v instead of 24v to increase the speed of the scooter. I've no idea how to inspect a PCB in a DC application and determine whether 50% over voltage will destroy it or whether it has a natural range of input voltages and (in the case of a motor controller) will vary the output as a percentage of the input

I'm keen to know in a general sense whether one can (and if so how to) identify whether a DC circuit is voltage specific or more tolerant of varied input voltages?

Comment: Using a device beyond its ratings is usually a bad idea. The WAP accepted a wide voltage range because it was designed to, and its ratings told you that. The Ethernet switch is low powered and so far you have been lucky. You won't be with the scooter, but you may be able to fit new components RATED for 36V to its smouldering remains.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you cannot know without understanding the circuit involved.

For instance, your scooter controller probably uses PWM to control motor speed, and the FETs used for power drive will almost certainly handle 36 volts as well as they do 24 - the lowest-voltage parts made usually start at about 50 volts, and it would cost more to get special parts than to use these over-rated parts. The same probably goes for the lower-level parts.

But maybe not.

Even if the controller parts will handle the increased voltage, it's entirely possible that the wiring won't, where "won't" is synonymous with "will melt the insulation and catch fire". And the motors themselves may well be damaged by application of over-voltage and/or over-current.

So the answer is really "no" on several levels. Not only can you not tell by simple, ignorant inspection, there are parts of the system other than the controller which may be damaged even if the controller survives.

You should take @Brian Drummond's phrase "smoldering remains" very seriously.